# Errors de-serializing XML: {"<query xmlns=''> was not expected."}

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, serialization

I normally work with json, but have to work with XML to use this data.

I've tried this several different ways but am unable to get this to deserialize.The typical error it throws is:

```
{"<query xmlns=''> was not expected."}
```

I think it's how I've set up the Query class. I've tried several different things with no luck. Hoping someone that knows more about XML can offer a suggestion. Thanks.

Here is the GetResult method that I call from a console app.

```
    public static Query GetResults()
    {
        string url = @"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.industry%20where%20id%20in%20(select%20industry.id%20from%20yahoo.finance.sectors)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        Query resultSet;

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Results));
                resultSet = (Query)serializer.Deserialize(responseStream);
            }
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
```

Here is the Results class:

```
namespace TheXMLService
{
[XmlRoot("query", Namespace = "http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng")]
public partial class Query
{
    [XmlElement("results", typeof(Results))]
    public Results results;
}

public class Results
{
    [XmlArrayItem("industry", typeof(Industry))]
    public Industry[] industry;
}
public class Industry
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")] 
    public int id;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")] 
    public string name;

    [XmlArrayItem("companies", typeof (Companies))] 
    public Companies[] companies;
}

public class Companies
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "company name")] 
    public string companyname;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "symbol")] 
    public string symbol;
}
}
```

And here is a chunk of the xml that gets returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="215"     yahoo:created="2014-02-12T18:40:10Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">

<results>
<industry id="112" name="Agricultural Chemicals">
<company name="Adarsh Plant Protect Ltd." symbol="ADARSHPL.BO"/>
<company name="AgriTec Systems, Inc." symbol="AGR.V"/>
<company name="Agrium Inc" symbol="AGU.DE"/>

... (many more companies here...

<company name="United Utilities Group PLC" symbol="UUEC.DE"/>
</industry>
</results>
</query>
<!-- total: 3288 -->
<!-- engine2.yql.bf1.yahoo.com -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you should change

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Results));
```

to

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Query));
```

and

```
[XmlRoot("query", Namespace = "http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng")]
```

to

```
[XmlRoot("query")]
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. The first one was a typo actually but deleting the namespace has at least changed the error. Now it appears to be an issue with the data being returned from Yahoo. I will be trying a few things...